# Convert upper cast to lower cast and Lower cast to upper cast in C#

Tags: c#

```
using System; 
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text;
class MyClass {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string str;
             char[] str1=str.ToCharArray();
         foreach (char c in inputArray)
    {
        if (char.IsLower(c))
       str += char.ToUpper(c);
        else
           str += char.ToLower(c);
    }

        System.Console.WriteLine("str");

            }
}
```

Error:tmp/CSHARP_30f1_944d_bf85_a405_1481953523/editor_source_509c_cad9_9662_9111_1481953523.cs(8,23): error CS0103: The name `inputArray' does not exist in the current context Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Comment: You don't need to do whatever that is, c# has a string to upper case function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewdd6aed(v=vs.110).aspx. Your exception is because 'inputArray' wasn't declared, pretty obvious if you read it.

Comment: Using str1 in declaration and using inputarray in loop copy code smells

Answer (score 1):

Try this code , for performance you should use StringBuilder class :

```
using System.Text;
public class MyClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        string input="AbCdEf";
        StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();

        foreach(char c in input){ 
            if(char.IsLower(c)){ 
                s1.Append(char.ToUpper(c));
            }else{
                s1.Append(char.ToLower(c));
            }


        }

    System.Console.WriteLine(s1.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: From performance perspective, using `StringBuilder` in this case is not the best.

Comment: @apocalypse it's better than string concatenation, but not the best, which will be to declare array with same length.

Comment: Thank Sir.

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str ="abcdE";
            string result = "";
                foreach (char c in str)
            {
                if (char.IsLower(c))
                    result += char.ToUpper(c);
                else if (char.IsUpper(c))
                    result += char.ToLower(c);
                else
                    result += char.ToLower(c);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}",result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

One line version using `System.Linq`

```
string input = "AAaaBBccDe";

var result = new String(input.Select(x => char.IsLower(x) ? char.ToUpper(x) : char.ToLower(x)).ToArray());
```